# Removing generic email addresses from a large excel database

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, email-filter

I have a large Excel sheet of contacts (26,000) that includes mostly specific email addresses but about 1%-3% are generic "info@" or "sales@" type.

These will get me into major doo doo if I use them with ConstantContact or similar email service. So I need to remove them without my eyes popping out of my head or spending $100.00 at UpWork to have someone to do it.

Any ideas of how to remove these from the list via filter or have them go to the top for deletion or whatever?

Comment: Sort, Select and Delete?

Comment: If you can describe the logic to identify generic email addresses, that logic can be used to work out a solution. If the logic is "the human in front of the computer recognises the generic email address" then that's what the approach will need to be.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn-I will meditate on that for a few decades:)

Comment: Perhaps you can post some mock-emails/data? Then we could see if there's at least some preliminary pattern we can find to help pull the generic addresses out.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

Collect all the usual generic email addresses' keywords (like *info@* or *sales@*, etc.) then `Ctrl + H` and replace these keywords with a special character an email cannot have. You can stop here as those email addresses wouldn't work anymore, or you can use thess special characters (eg. "##") for

- either for conditional formatting (highlight the cells, so easy to find and delete) or
- create an extra column (in column D), use the formula `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("##",C10))`, it gives you TRUE or FALSE

  - you can filter TRUE and delete those rows or
  - you can create another column (in column E) and use the formula to create a clean list `=IF(D10=TRUE;A10;"")`